# Update text on image in html

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have used em tags to write some text on an image. I want to provide some kind of functionality such that when a user types in text box this text comes over image. I have doubt which event listener should I add to text box so that as soon as change the content of text box it can change the content of image too. I just need to know can this be done with event listener or something more is needed.
I know how to change text in image but could not find out how should i update this image text dynamically.
Hope am clear with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative way to use pure javascript.

Add `onkeyup` in textbox and call a function that you have provided.

```
<input type="text" id="tbMain" onkeyup="keyup();">
```

When press the key up its will call `function keyup()`

[See more at here.](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/WHTXF/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot OammieR. onkeyup() is what i want. onchange() is called after user has finished typing..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox.addEventListener('change', function () { ... });
```

If you would it to appear after the user is finished, you can use:

```
textbox.addEventListener('blur', function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="submit"/>
    <em id="toChange" >asd</em>
  </body>
</html>
```

and jQuery is:

```
$('#submit').change(function() {
   $('#toChange').text( $('#submit').val());  
});
```

or use this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SX7n3/87/)

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange() event listener. I think it will work